# Execute custom sql for one property in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

As I understand it NHibernate has a build in support for timestamps. However, it appears you can only instruct NHibernate to never update the property or always update it.

In the project I am currently working on there are several tables which have both "`created_time`" and "`updated_time`", both are to be generated by the database.

I can't figure out how to instruct NHibernate to use "`getdate()`" for both properties nut only on insert for "`created_time`" and on insert and update for "`updated_time`".

Is this possible?

PS: I am working with a legacy database and I am not allowed to change it, so triggers etc. are not possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work around this by creating an Interceptor that sets those values, but offcourse, then those values are not generated by the DBMS offcourse ...

It might be a workaround, as I also don't know how to make sure that the DB populates those values, but I'm also interested in another solution for this issue. :)

Comment: In the end I settled for the interceptor solution, but would be nice if there was a special property for this.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of NHibernate are you using?

In 2.0, the "generated" tag on a property has three valid values:

- never (self-explanatory)
- insert(will retrieve the generated value only on inserts)
- always (always retrieves generated value).